# d3.js while going over example

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Going over below

http://bl.ocks.org/cloudshapes/5661984

And I have tough time understanding two things

Why is `this` in d3.mouse(this) svg ?? I thought I understand `this` but here I cannot understand how to derive at definition of `this`.

Also, while redrawing, what is d here? putting watcher on `d` doesn't work.

```
// Redraw the path:
  path
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d);})
```

I assume it is the current points but I don't understand this `d` at this point

Please help. thank you so much.

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var npoints = 100;
var ptdata = [];


var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d, i) { return d[0]; })
    .y(function(d, i) { return d[1]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var svgagain = d3.select("body").select("svg")
    .on("mousemove", function() { var pt = d3.mouse(this); tick(pt); });



var path = svg.append("g")
  .append("path")
    .data([ptdata])
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

function tick(pt) {

  // push a new data point onto the back
  ptdata.push(pt);

  // Redraw the path:
  path
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d);})


  // If more than 100 points, drop the old data pt off the front
  if (ptdata.length > npoints) {
      ptdata.shift();
  }
}
```

Answer to my question after reading the documentation based on suggestion was below

```
The specified listener is invoked in the same manner as other operator functions, being passed the current datum d and index i, with the this context as the current DOM element.
```

Comment: svg path created by using d attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path

Comment: ok, but how does the function tick gets the definition of `d` here?

Comment: Are you aware of the plentiful documentation available for D3? One sentence in the section covering [`selection.on()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#on) answers both points of your question: *"The specified listener is invoked in the same manner as other operator functions, being passed the current datum d and index i, with the this context as the current DOM element."*

Comment: OK, I think I deserve some negativity on my questions after reading this. Yes, it is perfectly clear and I think I have LOT more reading to do on official documentation on d3.  Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

svg line can be created by using two approach.

**- SVG line:-**
   Here line can be created using two coordinate (x1,y1),(x2,y2)

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
   <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```

**- SVG path:-**
 Path created using d element. By using d3 it's very easy

```
<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

**this** keyword uses to refer current element.
[Line chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569)